# XSL-T For All Attributes in All Child Elements When Duplicates in Attribute Names

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I have a XSL-T which is looping through all the child elements of an XML, and pushing those attributes into a single outputted element. However, there are duplicate attributes in these child elements (same attribute in multiple children), and the XSL is only providing one result for each (only one of the values in that attribute in the family). I also do not believe it is looking for all of the children of the children, and properly pushing these into the resulting attribute set.

I have tried using  a single dynamic XSL-T, and also by using N# XSL templates, with each specifically focusing on a single child element, and then hard-coding the child element's name into the outputted attribute -- the second approach is only giving results for the first template, so did not solve my problem. If my second approach can be fixed to work, that is fine. If there is a way to programatically do this in a dynamic manner (the first option), then really cool! XSL is powerful, so hopefully it can do this, and you all can assist!

Below is an example shaped like my XML document:

```
<JSON offset="0" total_rows="1337" millis="987">
<rows Attribute1="" Attribute2="" oid="0000001">
<Name Attribute1="FirstName" Attribute2="LastName">
<_id oid="1337"/>
</Name>
<Occupation oid="12345"/>
</rows>
</JSON>
```

Note that there are duplicate attributes between the parent, and the child elements. I can only get one set of these attributes using my dynamic code or hard-coded approach. Also, I am not sure if either approach is successfully trying to get the child of the child of rows-- since they are not working, I have not been able to confirm that.

My two XSL approaches:

Dynamic (Only returns one value for the attributes which are duplicated):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="JSON">
<DATAPARENT>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</DATAPARENT>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//rows">

        <xsl:element name="DataRow">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">                   

                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">  

                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">  

                        <xsl:value-of select="." />  

                    </xsl:attribute>

                    </xsl:for-each> 

        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hard-Coded (Less flexible, which is fine, but also not giving me anything but the first set of results with the rows_{name()}):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="JSON">
<DATAPARENT>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</DATAPARENT>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rows">

        <xsl:element name="DataRow">            

                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">  

                    <xsl:attribute name="rows_{name()}">  

                        <xsl:value-of select="." />  


                    </xsl:attribute>

                    </xsl:for-each> 

        </xsl:element>  

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//Name">

        <xsl:element name="DataRow">            

                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">  

                    <xsl:attribute name="Name_{name()}">  

                        <xsl:value-of select="." />  


                    </xsl:attribute>

                    </xsl:for-each> 

        </xsl:element>  

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//Occupation">

        <xsl:element name="DataRow">            

                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">  

                    <xsl:attribute name="Occupation_{name()}">  

                        <xsl:value-of select="." />  


                    </xsl:attribute>

                    </xsl:for-each> 

        </xsl:element>  

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you all for your suggestions and insights that can be provided. Please look at the XSL that I have already provided before suggesting basic approaches which just do element attribute looping; I am already using them, and it is the duplicate attribute issue I haven't resolved. Thanks!!

**EDIT: The desired output would be:

```
<DATAPARENT>
<DataRow rows_Attribute1="" rows_Attribute2="" rows_oid="0000001" Name_Attribute1="FirstName" Name_Attribute2="LastName" Name__id_oid="1337" Occupation_oid="12345" />
<DataRow rows_Attribute1="1" rows_Attribute2="2" rows_oid="0000002" Name_Attribute1="FirstName" Name_Attribute2="LastName" Name__id_oid="1254" Occupation_oid="99231" />
</DATAPARENT>**
```

I am aware that I can't have duplicate named attributes in XML, but I don't know how to programatically create the attribute name with a unique combination referencing the elements in the source.

Answer (score 0):

First:  In your first sample, you're writing out all the attributes of all the children of `rows` as attributes on one `DataRow` element, with the same name.  You're only getting one attribute with any given name (even if more than one attribute with that name occurs among the children) because XML only allows one attribute with any given name on an element.  Your output `DataRows` element can have one `oid` attribute, but it cannot have two, if the stylesheet is to produce XML output.

If you want one name-value pair for each attribute-value pair in the subtree, write them out as children of `DataRow`, not attributes.

Then:  You're not getting any attributes from grandchildren of `rows` (or their descendants) because your `xsl:for-each` iterates over children, not descendants.  You could rewrite the for-each as an apply-templates, possibly with a mode (which would make it easy to recur and which some XSLT programmers would find more idiomatic), or you could change `select="*"` to `"select="descendant::*"`.

Comment: Does select="descendant::* also provide me with the results from the higher levels of elements? If so, this is exactly how I would need to iterate through my elements and attributes, but I still need a way to reference the element name when declaring the outputted attribute name. Thanks!

Comment: Any good tutorial on XPath will explain `descendant` and the other XPath axes; finding and reading a few will be a good investment of time.  Note that your revised plan for your desired output will still generate duplicates whenever any two descendants have the same element name and attributes with the same name; that's why I suggested emitting elements instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the structure of my output, as it is needed for this output can be processed by the remainder of my application. Can you recommend an approach which does flatten this and provides a unique attribute name? I will take your advice re XPath when available.

Comment: I can *identify* several approaches for ensuring the uniqueness of names (`xsl:number` and `generate-id()` are two obvious choices), but no, I can't *recommend* them to you, because my hunch is that the right thing to do here is to revise the interface to the rest of your application rather than tie this part of your code in knots trying to satisfy what sound like implausible assumptions in the current design.

Comment: Uniqueness was achieved using the method I requested here, and leveraging two variables; one which is `localname()`, the other being `localname(parent::*)`. As I had thought, there was a readily available XSL means of identifying the source element when adding in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haven't shown your desired output, but it looks to me as if you are trying to create an element which has several attributes with the same name. That's not allowed in XML, so XSLT doesn't permit it.

If you try to add two attributes with the same name to the same element, XSLT takes the last one added; XQuery reports an error.

Comment: For everyone else's reference, this was the solution I eventually implemented. It added in uniqueness by creating two variables which were referenced in the attribute name, and point at the local name and the parent level's local name. If there are deeper levels of children needed, it would require additional iterations to be hard coded in.

My Solution: